# Reading Right recursion

Tags: parsing, recursion

I understand that in left recursion

A -> Aα | β

so A can be either β and stop or continue and have Aα infinite times since it is explained in its self. So If I were to parse βαα:

```
      A 
     / \
    A   α 
   / \
  Α   α
 /
β
```

I found that the same grammar in right recursion is the following:

A-> βA'

A'-> αA'|ε

I can do the parse tree for βαα again, but I can't read the production rules like in left recursion. Can someone explain the steps of reading the production rules in this right-recursive grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The production rules are applied in this order:

```
A -> 
  -> βA'   (apply A -> βA')
  -> βαA'  (apply A' -> αA')
  -> βααA' (apply A' -> αA')
  -> βαα   (apply A' -> ε)
```

The parse tree would look like this:

```
  A 
 / \
β   A' 
   / \
  α   A'
     / \
    α   A'
        |
        ε
```

---

### Removing direct left-recursion

each rule with direct left recursion:

```
A -> Aa | Ab | Ac | ... | x | y | z
```

is replaced by:

```
A  -> xA' | yA' | zA' | ...
A' -> aA' | bA' | cA' | ε
```

where `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `x`, `y`, `z` are sequences that do not begin with `A`.

Repeat this process until no direct left recursion remains.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm mostly interested in **how** to convert the left recursive grammar into a right recursive grammar. I did not come up with the right recursive grammar myself.